# Limit in mongoose for one query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

My schema:

```
export const MessagesAllSchema = new Schema({
  senderName: {type: String, required: true},
  senderId: {type: String, required: true},
  content: String,
  date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
  roomId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
});
```

My query:

```
AllMessages.find(
  {roomId: [roomId1, roomId2]},
  (err, messages) => {
    console.log(messages);
  },
).sort({date: -1});
```

**My code return**

My code returns several messages from room 1 and room 2.

**I want to achieve**

I want to my code return one message for room 1 and one message for room 2. If I apply .limi(2) I got a 2 message for room 1, but I want to get one message per room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with `find()`, You can try [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method,

- `$match` roomId in array of roomIds
- `$group` by `roomId` and get first message form multiple grouped messages in `root` variable
- `$replceWith` to replace root object in root
- `$sort` by date in descending order
- `$limit` 2 documents only

```
const messages = await AllMessages.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      roomId: { $in: [roomId1, roomId2] }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$roomId",
      root: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$root" },
  { $sort: { date: -1 } },
  { $limit: 2 }
]).exec();

console.log(messages);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-Cak1TNbGLD)